# Django related models aren't found in a view, but are in shell

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

For some reason when I check my user for related models in a view I get the following:

```
DoesNotExist at /user/profile/
User has no employee.
```

Which is being fired from the following line in my view's `get_object`:

```
 obj = self.request.user.employee
```

However, when I manually pull the same user (mgr) in `manage.py shell` you can see that it finds the relation given ID=2.

```
In [12]: Employee.objects.get(id=1)                                                                                                                                    
Out[12]: <Employee: firstname lastname>

In [13]: Employee.objects.get(id=1).user.first_name
Out[13]: u'firstname'

In [14]: User.objects.get(id=1)                                                                                                                                        
Out[14]: <User: meteorainer>

In [15]: User.objects.get(id=2)                                                                                                                                        
Out[15]: <User: mgr>

In [16]: User.objects.get(id=2).get_full_name
Out[16]: <bound method User.get_full_name of <User: mgr>>

In [17]: User.objects.get(id=2).get_full_name()
Out[17]: u'firstname lastname'

In [18]: User.objects.get(id=2).username                                                                                                                               
Out[18]: u'mgr'
```

It get's weirder.  When I log in as mgr whether or not that user also has a related `Employee`  I get this error.  However, if I am logged in as my superuser meteorainer (User.id=1), I NEVER get the error regardless of whether it is associated to a member or not.

***For clarity:***
I'm using this method to extend User https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Can you show the Employee model definition..?

Comment: I meant to come back and answer this question. Got it resolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my Employee model was inheriting from an abstract class.  The related name is what I wasn't using correctly.